# ¿Como soluciono una advertencia de importación en ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, tslint

al compilar mi app en ionic v3 me sale lo siguiente:

> tslint: C:/Users/Carlos
>   Soto/Desktop/Apps/App1/src/providers/localhost/localhost.ts, line: 3
>               All imports are unused.

```
   L2:  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   L3:  import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

la palabra import en L3 sale en Rojo en mi compilador, he investigado sin resultado positivo. ¿alguien puede ayudarme con esto?

Answer (score 2):

Significa que esa línea

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

sobra:

> All imports are unused

se puede traducir como:

*Ninguna de las importaciones es usada*

Es un aviso de **tslint**, que es una herramienta para ayudar a mantener el código limpio, así que no impide la ejecución ni es algo grave.